# How do I get the Antlr 4 rule name in C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to get the specific statement type name when parsing MySQL, using the Antlr4 generated C++ parser.

I am using the MySQL Antlr4 grammar from [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/library/parsers/grammars)

This is what I am using right now:

```
rule_index=SelectStatement()->getRuleIndex();
statement_type=getRuleNames()[rule_index];
```

This is for the SelectStatement branch, but now I have to do this for every statement type case. Is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO I think there is no better ANTLR specific solution that is generic, applicable to all rules without changing anything.

I use C#, and its possible to use reflection to get the name of the procedure where the call is made. From the name string, you can remove the decoration (e.g. in visitors, the method names start with "Visitor") to get the name of the method you are in. However, reflection is not the fastest technology to use.